# Cannot call location.getLocation in the background

Tags: flutter, firebase-cloud-messaging, location, background-process

Package used:https://pub.dev/packages/location

My code:

```
void main() async {
    await Firebase.initializeApp();
    FirebaseMessaging.onBackgroundMessage(messageHandler);
}

Future<void> messageHandler(RemoteMessage message) async {
loc.Location location = new loc.Location();
  printcolor('location obj : $location', color: DColor.blue);
  bool _serviceEnabled;
  loc.LocationData _locationData;

  bool backgroundEnable = await location.enableBackgroundMode(enable: true).catchError((onError) {
    printcolor('getLocation error : $onError', color: DColor.red);
  });
  printcolor('background enable : $backgroundEnable', color: DColor.yellow);
  _locationData = await location.getLocation().catchError((onError) {
    printcolor('getLocation error : $onError', color: DColor.red);
  });
  printcolor('location : ${_locationData.latitude},${_locationData.longitude}', color: DColor.green);
}
```

Report an error

```
I/flutter (17042): nulllocation obj : Instance of 'Location'
I/flutter (17042): nullgetLocation error : MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method enableBackgroundMode on channel lyokone/location)
I/flutter (17042): nullbackground enable : null
I/flutter (17042): nullgetLocation error : MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method getLocation on channel lyokone/location)
I/flutter (17042): FlutterFire Messaging: An error occurred in your background messaging handler:
I/flutter (17042): NoSuchMethodError: The getter 'latitude' was called on null.
I/flutter (17042): Receiver: null
I/flutter (17042): Tried calling: latitude
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION"/>
```

I use FCM to start background execution. When the dependency is only location package and FCM package, the location can be obtained in the background.

But after adding the flutter_facebook_login: ^3.0.0 package, the location cannot be obtained in the background.